# how does this sentence(yield "lines", 1) work in mrjob's Official document

Tags: python, mrjob

I'm trying to understand the official example for mrjob clearly

```
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

I can basically understand the thought of MapReduce.but,how does this sentence(yield "lines", 1) work? What's the meaning of "1" ？

Comment: Have a look at the answers to the following question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: thanks friend,it really helped me understand what is "yield", Is it correct for me to understand in this way: cause field is an generator,it will be called n times, n equals line's number, so let the lines's value =1, then we can count line number through sum(values)

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns a tuple: ("lines", 1). Parentheses can be omitted for tuples in situations like this. Each `yield` returns some aspect of the input, as well as the aspect's value. The number of lines is 1.

The line could have been written like this:

```
yield ("lines", 1)
```

Comment: these code is used to count myfile_txt's chars、words and lines,as example says

Comment: field is an generator,it will be called n times, n equals line's number，equals 1 means that can count a sum